# How do I open a page outside of the iframe but within the same tab?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Part of my javascript code opens a new page when a password is entered but that password page just so happens to be inside an iframe. Therefore it opens the new page inside that iframe which is not what i want, but I don't want it to open a new tab either.

How do I make it so that the page is opened outside the iframe but in the same tab? I've tried the "target" attribute but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right because it does nothing.

The JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function redirect() {
  var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
  switch (input) {
    case 'INTRODUCE':
      window.location.replace('allwhy.html');
      break;
    case 'VIRTUALIZATION':
      window.location.replace('xxxx2.html');
      break;
    default:
      window.location.replace(' ');
      break;
  }

}
</script>
```

I've tried putting
`<base target="_parent">`
in the  section of the HTML but like I said, that isn't working. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

`<base>` will only affect links. You are changing the location via JavaScript.

Use `parent.location` or `top.location`